# What is the difference between System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired. and System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired

Tags: sql, .net, timeout, sqlexception

I have a number of SQL timeouts I am logging. Recently, the stack trace errors that contained **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.** stopped occurring. However, I still get plenty of the ones that look like **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired.**

I was getting both prior to whatever changed. I can't find anything detailing why the .NET framework spits out one or the other. I know both are caused by the SQL being executed doesn't finish before the command timeout. Just looking for what is the difference.

Answer (score 0):

It is about the .Net Framework installed. 
For us with the installation of 4.7.2 we started getting 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired.' 
instead of the previous one: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.'